# Google Sheets: Perform Filter() on an array

Tags: google-sheets

thanks everyone. Appreciate everyone's input.

Is it possible for the Filter() formula to perform on an array, such as:

**Filter(A:A,B:B={D:D})**

The reason is, I need to obtain {D:D} from another formula that produces the array.

For example, {D:D} becomes {Red;Green}. Ideally, in this case output would be {1;2;4}

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Red |
| 2 | Red |
| 3 | Blue |
| 4 | Green |

I believe there are similar methods using arrayformula(vlookup()). However the output in that case becomes {1;4} as it'd only give the first match for Red.

Thanks again for taking the time to read this. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `QUERY()` function in this way.

```
=QUERY(A2:B,"select A, B where B matches '" & TEXTJOIN("|",TRUE,UNIQUE(D:D)) & "'")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=FILTER(A:A, REGEXMATCH(B:B&"", TEXTJOIN("|", 1, D:D))
```